# Using character vectors in for loop (R)

Tags: r

I have a dataset full of survey measures by item and I want to write code to test the reliability of each measure and save it to a new object. I'd like to accomplish this using a for loop.

For example, for a measure called "ffmq" with columns ffmq1:ffmq24 in data = baseline, i have the following code which gives me an object ffmq.alpha that contains the alpha value of my measure:

```
ffmq <- baseline %>%
  select(starts_with("ffmq"))
ffmq.rel <- psych::alpha(ffmq, check.keys = TRUE)
ffmq.alpha <- ffmq.rel$total$raw_alpha
ffmq.alpha
```

I created a vector with my measure names:

```
measures <- c("ffmq", "DERSaware", "DERSgoals", "DERSnonaccept")
```

Can anyone help me use a for loop with my character vector to create all of the alpha variables?

Comment: I don't understand this entirely (this is likely a me problem and not a you problem) but would a `pivot_longer` and then `group_by` operation do instead?

Comment: I think you are making a mistake by assuming a for loop is the way to do this.  Why not just state the problem and let answerers make suggestions? Also are you restricted to base R or would you use a package?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).